# Is there any difference between SVN rename and delete, add

Tags: svn

I have renamed a file from file explorer then I added the new file to SVN and deleted the previous file from terminal. and then the svn showing

```
D <FileName>
A <NewFileName>
```

Once I did svn rename I found that svn is also doing the same thing

```
D <FileName>
A <NewFileName>
```

Is there any difference between svn rename and svn delete, add?

Comment: If you delete a file from Windows explorer it won't show up as *deleted* but as *missing*.

Comment: sorry I am using ubuntu and I deleted the file from file browser window.(As I am familiar with windows I used to say explorer ;) )

Comment: @GilsonPJ what's the point in using `visualsvn` and `tortoisesvn` tags then?

Comment: sorry I will remove that tag. I thought about to getting more visibility to the question. I will remove it now.

Comment: I'll rephrase my comment then: if you remove a file from file system (rather than using a Subversion client) it'll show up as *missing*. If yours is *deleted* that means that your GUI tool is SVN-aware and did the right thing for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is. Subversion records moves and renames as `svn copy` followed by `svn delete`, and beginning with SVN 1.9 saves a link between the source and target file.

- [SVN 1.9. | Working copy records moves as first-class operation](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#moves)
- [SVN 1.9 | `svn status` and `svn info` now show local moves](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#svn-status-info-moves)

Comment: You can see the subtle difference in *commit* or *check for modifications* dialogues: `added (+)` vs just `added` with further info on mouse hover.